# Algorithm - minimum diameter spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

Please suggest an algorithm for creating minimum diameter spanning tree from an undirected graph.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041520/algorithm-for-minimum-diameter-spanning-tree

Comment: The soulotion in the link is not accepted yet. Is it correct?

Comment: @Alireza Yes. It was deleted for being link-only, so I posted another answer with a lot more detail.